# Running SQL queries from inside spreadsheet cells

Tags: sql-server, excel, t-sql, scripting

I have an Excel spreadsheet with several SQL queries stored in different cells and I'd like to execute these queries on SQL Server to generate a new sheet where each cell is the query result from the original spreadsheet. The idea behind this is to preserve the sheet formatting when generating the results (conditional formatting and etc.).

Something like this:

Input spreadsheet:

| Database | Information A | Information B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DB 1 | SQL Query 1 | SQL Query 2 |
| DB 2 | SQL Query 3 | SQL Query 4 |

Output spreadsheet:

| Database | Information A | Information B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DB 1 | Result of Query 1 | Result of Query 2 |
| DB 2 | Result of Query 3 | Result of Query 4 |

I wasn't able to find ideas on how to do exactly this during my research of the subject, but I do believe it should be doable using either VBA or some scripting language.

Any thoughts on how should I approach this?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). Having a query in an Excel Sheet's cell going to easily open you to all sorts of security issues.

Comment: The main idea behind using an Excel Spreadsheet is to have all query results inserted into an already preformatted sheet (with conditional formatting rules and etc). I don't necessarily need to run the queries from inside excel, but I do need to preserve the sheet formatting for the output.

Comment: Here in SO you have multiple examples about connecting Excel and SQL and how to import data. Your question now is too broad. You should focus and try something.

Comment: This looks like the scenario for Power Query. You can try to use it to get data from multiple data sources and combine it into the useful result set. On top of that resultset you can creat your presntation layer in the excel spreadsheet.

Comment: @JacekWróbel

Yeah, looks like Power Query was the answer. I've got it running now it and it does the job perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got it done using Power Query. It was way easier than I thought. Special thanks to Jacek Wróbel for providing the idea in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

As an aside, you could do something like this.

```
Sub ADOExcelSQLServer()
     
    Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim Server_Name As String
    Dim Database_Name As String
    Dim User_ID As String
    Dim Password As String
    Dim SQLStr As String
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
     
    Server_Name = "EXCEL-PC\SQLEXPRESS" ' Enter your server name here
    Database_Name = "Northwnd" ' Enter your  database name here
    User_ID = "" ' enter your user ID here
    Password = "" ' Enter your password here
    SQLStr = "SELECT * FROM Orders" ' Enter your SQL here
     
    Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Cn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & _
    ";Uid=" & User_ID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"
     
    rs.Open SQLStr, Cn, adOpenStatic
    
    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:Z500")
        .ClearContents
        .CopyFromRecordset rs
    End With
    
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Cn.Close
    Set Cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

That sits in a VBA Module.  Of course, you could store the SQL in an Excel cell, and do this...

```
SQLStr = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
```

Also, you could loop through a bunch of cells and run a bunch of SQL jobs.

Your own imagination is your only limitation.